# Bonfire vs stock CodeIgniter - module compatability

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I've been using CodeIgniter for a few months and recently discovered Bonfire, which looks like a great foundation for CI projects, despite the current build using almost outdated resources like Bootstrap 2.

I really love the module system in Bonfire, it seems like a very efficient method for creating completely independent subsystems. However, I wonder how compatible these modules would be with a normal CodeIgniter installation. Obviously you can't just dump the modules folder in, CI wouldn't know what to do with it, but is there any way to restructure a BF module into a third party plugin or something that can be used in CI?

Similarly, would it be possible to extract files from a CI installation and package them as a BF module (obviously with some tweaking)?

I would imagine the answer to those questions would probably be "of course not", so I just want to make my understanding clear; if I decide to develop with Bonfire, I would essentially be stuck using it without being able to revert to vanilla CodeIgniter and I would only be able to share my modules with other Bonfire users. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the very first difference is that bonfire works on **HMVC (Hierarchical model–view–controller)** which means every module will contain its own `model view and controller`.

Yes it can easily be integrate with the vanilla codeIgniter you mentioned because the framework basically following the codeIgniter rules and provided a CMS with great functions.

Some features like:

1. Built-In Admin Area
2. Modular Coding
3. Data Maintenance

For more details check the [documentation](http://cibonfire.com/learn)